# Why does std::numeric_limits<SomeStruct>::infinity() "work"?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, std, c++17

I accidentally fed a default initializeable `struct` to `std::numeric_limits<somestruct>::infinity()`. What I got back was a default struct.

Why does the standard allow this to compile and return such an unexpected value?

```
#include <iostream>

struct somestruct {
    uint64_t a = 7;
};

inline ::std::ostream& operator <<(::std::ostream& s, const somestruct& q) {
    s << q.a;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    constexpr const auto inf = ::std::numeric_limits<somestruct>::infinity();
    std::cout << inf << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt for compilation](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+somestruct+%7B%0A++++uint64_t+a+%3D+7%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ainline+::std::ostream%26+operator+%3C%3C(::std::ostream%26+s,+const+somestruct%26+q)+%7B%0A%09s+%3C%3C+q.a%3B%0A%09return+s%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char+**argv)+%7B%0A%09constexpr+const+auto+inf+%3D+::std::numeric_limits%3Csomestruct%3E::infinity()%3B%0A%09std::cout+%3C%3C+inf+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:47.985347985347985,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:52.01465201465201,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) verification

Comment: You're missing a header file. That it builds without including `<limits>` is pure coincidence. And what *is* the "unexpected value" you get in return?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: "A default struct"

Comment: What else did you expect? You did not tell the computer what "infinity" means for your `somestruct` type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I might be nitpicking, but "a default struct" is not a "value".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Here it appears to be short for "an instance of my class `somestruct` with its only member default-initialised"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Why" questions are notoriously unanswerable, but the direct answer is: that's how [it's specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.limits#1):

> ```
> namespace std {
>   template<class T> class numeric_limits {
>     // ...
>     static constexpr T infinity() noexcept { return T(); }
>     // ...
>   };
> }
> ```

With the [extra text](http://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.limits#members-49) that `infinity()` is:

> Meaningful for all specializations for which `has_­infinity != false`

In your case, `numeric_limits<somestruct>::has_infinity` is `false`, so `infinity()` isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

According to C++17 [numeric.limits]/1 the default for the function in question is:

```
static constexpr T infinity() noexcept { return T(); }
```

You haven't defined any specialization, so you get the default.

[cppreference.com link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity)